# How do I list entries with check boxes in android?

Tags: android

[image]

Hi,

I'm new to Android. I want to develop this UI screen where at top I have the header and below to it I've to list entries from a file at run time. Each entry should have a checkbox. I should be able to select an entry and delete it by clicking on the delete button. How can I develop this? What all topics I should look into to develop this UI screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to list entries with checkboxes. My post[[Binary XML file line #9 : Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834513/binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-fragment]) contains the relevant code.